# SoA SIMD vector-matrix multipliation

Tags: matrix-multiplication, simd

Is there any standard way of doing matrix multiplication of vectors in SoA arrangements? As, I understand in SoA I can use 3-vectors (where each component is in separate array) and for basic operations use 3x3 matrix (rotation/scale) combined with vector addition for translation. The opposite will be AoS using 4x4 matrix and 4-vector multiplication for whole transformation (but, wasting one component for 0 or 1). Implementing the latter look trivial (store matrix in 4 SIMD registers, load next vector, do job (muls/adds), store vector). However, I have trouble how to do multiplication with 3x3 matrix - it looks like I need 9 SIMD registers for the matrix only - each matrix component tuned to 4-vector of same values. But, I have only 8 registers so I will need to store intermediates (which will be more load/store instructions). So, is there any clever way?

Comment: Usually you have a whole 3x3 matrix stored contiguously, not as 3 separate rows.  Having 3x rows as 3 separate vectors would let you broadcast a column element and multiply more simply, I guess, but it's a tradeoff between data density (wasting 1 of 4 elements of a vector multiply) vs. more shuffling.  I haven't looked at 3x3 multiply for SSE or NEON (or whatever you're using?), but maybe google up some Q&As about that.  I know there are some.

Comment: Thx, I didn't think of shuffling. So, now I see clearly it is speed vs memory footprint. As memory/bandwidth is not a problem in my case, AoS would win here. Shuffling will eat at least 2 more cycles and I don't have too much of them. A processor is kinda exotic - Apollo Core Vampire II (M68k on steroids).

Comment: If you do the required multiplies 4 at a time instead of 3 at a time, shuffling can be a speed win as well, in theory.  Depends on the microarch and ISA: efficiency of shuffle instructions vs. throughput / latency of FP multiply and add.  That's the tradeoff.  On a microarch with efficient broadcasts and lots of FMA throughput (like Intel Skylake), less shuffling probably wins.  But maybe on Ryzen where multiple shuffles per clock are possible but only one FMA per clock, maybe more shuffling wins.  IDK where your CPU falls on that spectrum.

Comment: If by SoA you mean multiplying a 3x3 matrix and 3-vector of 4d-arrays, this can be easily done with Eigen: https://godbolt.org/z/3K0PKv. No idea how this will translate to your target (which is definitely not natively supported by Eigen, but maybe auto-vectorization works).

Comment: For my arch most of these operations (add, mul, shuffle) are one CPU cycle. So shuffling vs mul another vector is simply the same. There is bandwidth issue (out of cache, which may be higher for 4 vector than for 3-vector). I doubt it will overtake the CPU time - but I will try to check it.

The Eigen code loops over 3 vector components, but I want to load matrix once and loop over. However, I was mistaken about the number of registers. There is 32 of them, so I can load whole matrix (splat into 9 registers), translation (splat into 3 regs) and four 3-vectors. This solves issue.